# How to save state of linux in virtual machine after powering off?

Tags: linux

I am using puppy linux (tahr64-6.0.5) in virtualbox.

Everytime I power off/send shutdown signal, it resets to original state (doesn't remember installed applications etc).

When I shut down for the first time (which is currently everytime), puppy linux asks me to save state when I shut down. However, the save fails because there is no storage (assuming because it is in virtual machine) and I am back to square one on the next boot.

The only way it saves state is that I choose save state from virtualbox option.

This means that I might never be able to shut it down.

Is there an elegant way to shut it down within puppy linux and it still saves the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you will be able to save state. The only way would be in virtual box as you stated. Is puppy booted from a live image? If so no settings or anything will ever be saved.

Comment: Live image means .iso file, right? If so, yes I set it up using the .iso file. So the only way save anything is to install linux physically on the hard disk (outside virtualbox)?

Comment: No.  Typically persistence for livecd/dvd images of Linux (running from tftp/pxe boot, boot from cd, boot from cd-image-on-usb) involves a partition with a specific volume label, wtih etiher the boot process looking for it automatically or being told to look for it via a boot argument (like "persistent" or similar).  So if anything you'd need to create a disk in virtualbox, partition it properly, etc.  Although if you are using virtualbox why not just install puppy to a virtual hard drive? http://puppylinux.org/wikka/InstallationFullHDD

Answer (score 0):

you can directly save state using menu-> machine -> take snapshot. this works for virtual box. Later you can load from where you left.